# remove blank page between acronym and nomenclature ? with example

Tags: page-breaking, acronyms, nomenclature, blank-page, clearpage

I have  a problem that occurs between chapter acronym and nomenclature. I dont know why, but a blank page appears.

my main coding looks like this:

```
%MINI_BSP_Nomenclature 



\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,headsepline]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Umlaute
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} % Deutschsprachiges Paket
\usepackage[]{acronym}  % Abkürzungsverzeichnis

\begin{document}

%------------------- Abkürzungsverzeichnis -----------------
\inputencoding{utf8}\input{Abkuerzungsverzeichnis.tex}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abkürzungsverzeichnis} % Abkürzungsverzeichnis in das Inhaltsverzeichnis einbinden


%-------------------- Nomenklatur -------------------------
% \chapter*{Nomenklatur}
\inputencoding{utf8}\input{Nomenklatur.tex}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Nomenklatur}



\end{document}
```

the file nomenclature:

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% -*- coding: UTF-8; -*-
% vim: set fenc=utf-8

\addchap*{Nomenklatur}
\section*{Lateinische Nomenklatur}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\begin{tabular}{l l l l l}
\bfseries{Symbol} && \textbf{Bedeutung} && \textbf{SI-Einheit} \\
$A$ && Fläche && $m^2$ \\
\end{tabular}

%\section*{Lateinische Nomenklatur}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\begin{tabular}{l l l l l}
\bfseries{Symbol} && \textbf{Bedeutung} && \textbf{SI-Einheit} \\
$k$ && turbulente kinetische Energie && $J/kg$\\
$l$ && charakteristische Lauflänge && $m$\\
$m$ && Masse && $kg$ \\
$\dot{m}$ && Massenstrom && $kg/s$\\
$p$ && Druck && $N/m^2$\\
\end{tabular}

%\section*{Lateinische Nomenklatur}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\begin{tabular}{l l l l l}
\bfseries{Symbol} && \textbf{Bedeutung} && \textbf{SI-Einheit} \\
$w$ && Geschwindigkeitskomponente && $m/s$ \\

\end{tabular}




\section*{Griechische Nomenklatur}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\begin{tabular}{l l l l l}
\bfseries{Symbol} & \textbf{Bedeutung} & \textbf{SI-Einheit} \\

$\alpha$ & Steigungswinkel & $^\circ$ \\
$\delta_{x}$ & Grenzschichtdicke & $ - $\\

\end{tabular}

\section*{Sonderzeichen}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\begin{tabular}{l l l l l}
\bfseries{Symbol} & \textbf{Bedeutung} & \textbf{SI-Einheit} \\
$\nabla$ && Nabla-Operator && $-$ \\
\end{tabular}
```

and acronym:

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
% -*- coding: UTF-8; -*-
% vim: set fenc=utf-8




%----- Abkuerzungsverzeichnis ------

\chapter*{Abkürzungsverzeichnis}


\begin{acronym}[CFD]
\acro{Abb}{Abbildung}
\acro{AG}{Aktiengesellschaft}
\end{acronym}
```

I dont know what is wrong with the coding. Hopefully someone can help me

Comment: Some document classes attempt to start each chapter on the left hand side, and therefore would add a blank between chapters ending on the left (acronyms on the left, empty page on right, nomenclature on left). See if you can define the document to be one sided...

Answer (score 1):

solved that problem

had an `\onehalfspacing` in my main coding